# Place horizontal lines on the chart, based on average percentage change in daily price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have 2 problems with this code. It basically takes the percentage change in price from the daily chart day by day. And I would like that when using the plot of the "mediaVariation" variable, a panel would be displayed below the graph and then directly on the graph, I would like the value of the "mediaVariation" variable added to the value of the closing price of the previous day to place a horizontal line on the result directly on the chart (resistance) and decreased from the previous day's closing value to place support on the chart. At the moment, to use "mediaVariation" in a panel below the chart, I have to manually go to the indicator and click to move to the panel below, ideally automatically and the horizontal lines don't work as expected

I've tried so many ways that I don't remember them all, but

for horizontal line:

```
plotShape()
line.new()
hline()
```

To the panel below the chart

`plot` with panel properties and histograms

but without success

Here's the code

```
//@version=5
indicator("Média de Variação", shorttitle="Média Variação", overlay=true)

// Parâmetros
period = input.int(20, title="Período")
dateType = input.int(2, title="Tipo de Dado (1: Range, 2: Variação %)")
mediaType = input.int(0, title="Tipo de Média (0: Aritmética, 1: Exponencial, 2: Welles Wilder, 3: Ponderada)")

// Variáveis
variation = 0.0
mediaVariation = 0.0

// Cálculo da Variação
if dateType == 1
    variation := high - low
else if dateType == 2
    variation := ((close - close[1]) / close[1]) * 100

// Função para calcular o valor absoluto
absValue(src) =>
    src >= 0 ? src : -src

// Cálculo da Média
if mediaType == 0
    mediaVariation := ta.sma(variation, period)
else if mediaType == 1
    mediaVariation := ta.ema(variation, period)
else if mediaType == 2
    // Calcular a média móvel de Welles Wilder usando sma
    sum = ta.sma(variation, period)
    mediaVariation := sum / period
else if mediaType == 3
    mediaVariation := ta.wma(variation, period)

plot(mediaVariation, title="Média de Variação", color=color.blue)
```